# Изменение файла через ssh посредством ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

Посредством подключения через ssh необходимо выполнить скрипт на удаленной машине. Не могу разобраться с sed. А точнее, как он взаимодействует с передаваемыми переменными

Пример:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
A=«java.extended.prop=-XX\:NewSize\=1024m -XX\:MaxNewSize\=1024m -XX\:PretenureSizeThreshold\=10m»

ssh root@10.2.200.172 "
B=\$(echo $A | cut -d «=» -f 2-)
touch /tmp/test.txt echo «java.extended» > /tmp/test.txt
cat /tmp/test.txt
sed -i '/java/a \$B' /tmp/test.txt
cat /tmp/test.txt "
```

Результат работы будет таков:

java.extended
   $B

Как правильно передать sed переменную, вычисленную на удаленной машине, чтобы получить необходимую мне запись?

Что должно получиться:

java.extended
   -XX:NewSize\=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize\=1024m -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold\=10m

Comment: у вас «поехала» разметка в вопросе. я очень приблизительно её восстановил, но полностью ваш замысел известен только вам. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. рекомендую ознакомиться с [разделом справки по форматированию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @aleks.andr Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете записпть результат выполнения скрипта/команды на удаленной машине в переменную на локальной, а потом уже обработать этот результат на локальной машине.

```
FIRST_VAR="very long text"
SECOND_VAR=`ssh username@servername "some_remote_script $FIRST_VAR ...."`
echo $SECOND_VAR | sed ...
```

Попробуйте так.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно на машину, инициирующую ssh-соединение, передать результат выполнения скрипта на целевой машине, так?

Тогда можете перенаправить вывод вашего скрипта в файл, а затем получить этот файл обратно так:

```
scp local/path/to/file/file_name user@host:/remote/path/to/save/file
```

Man по scp [здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=scp&category=1&russian=0).

PS: возможно при всём этом вам придётся настроить аутентификацию ssh по публичному ключу ([Подробнее](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=ssh-keygen&category=1) об ssh-keygen) .